# How can I route to a module?

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have poured over the documentation but I can't seem to find out how I can route a URI to a module.

My module currently contains a single controller using the correct directory structure (currently a ton of empty directories).  I have my controller inside `modules/module_name/classes/controller` and my routes file inside `modules/module_name/config/routes.php`.

I have tried the following in both `/app/config/routes.php` and `modules/module_name/config/routes.php`:

```
<?php
return array(
    '_root_'  => 'md5_encrypt/index',  // The default route

    'tools/geek/md5_encrypt' => array('md5_encrypt'),
);
```

The controller looks like below (but I don't think that is relevant):

```
<?php

/**
 * MD5 Encrypt Controller.
 *
 * Online tool to encrypt a string using MD5
 * 
 * @package  app
 * @extends  Controller
 */

namespace Md5_encrypt;

class Controller_Md5_Encrypt extends Controller_Template
{

    /**
     * The tool
     * 
     * @access  public
     * @return  Response
     */
    public function action_index()
    {
        $data = array();
        $this->template->tab = 'geek';
        $this->template->title = 'MD5 Encrypt Tool';
        $this->template->content = View::forge('welcome/index', $data);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an underscore in a namespace name. Same for the controller name.

The autoloader will convert underscores to directory separators when looking for the file.

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't fixed it.  I would imagine it would have errored were the routes working

Answer (score 0):

First you should set the path of your application modules in app/config/config.php

```
'module_paths' => array(
    APPPATH.'modules'.DS, // path to application modules
)
```

Second set routing in app/config/routes.php

```
'tools/geek/md5_encrypt' => 'md5_encrypt(module_name)/md5_encrypt(controller)',
```

However, since you are using underscore for your Controller's Name `class Controller_Md5_Encrypt extends Controller_Template`, it resulted to a new path.

```
/modules/md5_encrypt/classes/controller/md5/encrypt.php
```

**Underscore(_)** in your Controller's name was converted to a directory separator during autoloading http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/coding_standards.html#classes

Your `/modules/md5_encrypt/classes/controller/md5_encrypt.php` file was not found during autoloading.